# undefined method `to_key' for #<User::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x007f1bf8c2fd60>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I am really new at rails so please forgive me if i can't see it.

I am trying to edit the permissions on each individual user and i am getting this error in form_for:

```
undefined method `to_key' for #<User::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x007f1bf8c2fd60>
```

From what i have seen on other questions on stackoverflow, this usually happens when you try to call a collection in a form but this is not the case?

view:

```
<div class="n-container">
<tr-form data-riot riot-tag="tr-form">
<%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>

    <section>
        <div class="w-container">
            <h1>User permissions</h1>
            <% @permissions.each do |permission| %>
                <%= check_box_tag 'permission_ids[]', permission.id %>
                <div>
                    <%= permission.description %>
                </div>
            <% end %>
        </div>
    </section>

    <section>

      <div class="f-controls align-right">
        <%= f.submit class: "btn fill blue", value: "Submit" %>
      </div>

    </section>
<% end %>
</tr-form>
</div>
```

users_controller:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
    def user_params
        params.require('user').permit(
            permissions: []
        )
    end

    def permissions
        @user = User.where(id: params[:user_id])
        @permissions = Permission.all
    end
end
```

routes:

```
resources :users do
  get 'permissions'
  post 'permissions'
end
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29005090/how-to-solve-undefined-method-to-key-for-bookactiverecord-relation0x007fb?rq=1

Comment: your @user seems to be a relation, not a `User` instance

Comment: `User.where` returns an collection (=`ActiveRecord::Relation`). Call `first` to get the first one, or more ideomatic: use `User.find` instead.

Answer (score 2):

One should use [`ActiveRecord::FinderMethods#find`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/FinderMethods.html#method-i-find), not `where`, to receive a single instance:

```
def permissions
    # WRONG: where returns a relation
    # @user = User.where(id: params[:user_id])
    @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
    @permissions = Permission.all
end
```

It worth to mention, that `find` raise a `RecordNotFound` exception on fail, hence you probably want to rescue from it:

```
def permissions
    @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
    @permissions = Permission.all
rescue RecordNotFound => rnf
    # Log or just skip
end
```

---

`where` might be [ab]used here as well, but in such a case you need to explicitly say that you need the only user:

```
@user = User.where(id: params[:user_id]).first
```